# Wordpress Woocommerce theme's Header is not transparent like in the original demo

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, header, transparent

I just installed the Woocommerce theme "Organik" on my test website.
I imported the preset templates and selected "Organik House" as my Home page.

Now the issue is, The header in my website has a solid white background colour while the demo has a transparent one. Even after scrolling down the home, the overlay header colour stays white while on the demo it goes dark grey.

I can't figure out what the issue is. It looks like a css issue, Idk for sure.

Here is the demo site:

```
http://organik.thememove.com/organik-house/?header_type=header-03
```

Here is my test site:

```
https://hameedhudeen.tk/1/
```

---

I have checked the theme customisation settings already and the header colour is selected as transparent. Still the header is white.

Comment: please check header in admin area. 
I think there is a white background given

Comment: Ya, I've checked it already. The colour is selected as transparent.

Comment: Contact the theme author for support/documentation/how-to queries.

Comment: @Hameed - Feel free to post an answer, but please don't edit your question to contain an answer.

Comment: @David I'm sorry but is there something wrong in it? I thought it would be helpful to other having similar issues.

Comment: @Hameed - sharing your answer is *great* - but not as an edit to your question. I am merely suggesting you post the answer as a proper answer (and remove the edited "answer" part from your question). Placing an answer inside a question really isn't valid: it cannot be up/downvoted, and it cannot be accepted as an answer.

Comment: @David - Ok done brother!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you need to check options in wp-admin > appearance > customize. Sometime themes provide few options regarding Header there.

I have checked it and it looks like your ".content" div is not starting from top of the body. Your "header" is already transparent. If you have still an issue, let me check it out.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for looking into it. I'm not well-versed in coding stuff. It would be great if you could assist me with this. How do I contact you? I don't find any PM option here :/

Comment: @AnilK. - this is not the place to promote external contact.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
User **Anil K** helped me solve the issue.
It was not a css issue. It was due to mismatched settings.
Here is the solution provided by him

> Hi bro... there were some settings for particular page in bottom when
>   you edit the page like homepage. We disable the padding, title and
>   upload the white logo for homepage only from there. This is not a
>   issue but we are missing few settings.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgW9e.jpg)

Thanks bro! :)